# Flutter sqflite database with firestore

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app in flutter, but I want to be able to store the data in SQL database them synchronize with Firestone when the app goes online, I know it's possible but I don't know how. Please kindly help

An example on how it's done

Comment: You can use this library. The system keeps the data inside the phone. Even if you close the application, it remains there. Until you delete it. https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Comment: I know about this library, it's stores the data on the phone but I want to be able to store the data on firebase too, so there's is a backup of data in the cloud if the person loose is phone